# Need some good video tutorials

Tags: grammar

Can you guys suggest me some good easy to understand English learning video tutorials to download?

Comment: http://www.engvid.com/  came up on google.

Comment: You might care to have a look at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This probably belongs on Meta and should form part of the [General Reference/Resource question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online)

Comment: Why -1 for this question?

Comment: @DushyantJoshi I didn't downvote, but I imagine that whoever downvoted did so because this question is too open ended and doesn't really have a correct answer, have a look at the help section [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). You would be better off asking a question like this in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Educator.com](http://www.educator.com), English learning series. They are very useful for me and i learned a lot of them. You can find them for download in Google.
The English learning series in Educator.com contains:

- English Grammar
- English Composition
- Application Essays
- AP English Language & Composition
- AP English Literature & Composition
- Shakespeare: Plays & Sonnets
- Reading Comprehension